Distribution of a Uniform between Two Gaussians
I am having some problems with this question:
given two IID standard gaussians $X_1, X_2\sim\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, let $Y_1, Y_2$ the correspondent order statistics such that $Y_1 < Y_2$, then let $Z\sim\text{Unif}(Y_1, Y_2)$, can we write explicitly the CDF of $Z$?
I have tried solving it by conditioning on both $X_1, X_2$ but I got stuck with the computations:
$$P(Z < z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}P(Z<z|X_1=x)f_{X_1}(x)dx$$
where $f_{X_1}$ is the PDF of the standard normal and the integrated again over $X_2$ doing the two cases when it's below or above $X_1$.
But I get stuck.
Is there a way we can infer explicitly this distribution? Or if there is not a way, what is the best reasonable approximation we can make?
Edit: After a simulation (see my answer below), it turned out the $Z$ is very well approximated by a $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{2}{3})$, is there an intuitive reason for this? Or is it just a coincidence?

Welcome to MSE! Very interesting problem, I've been working on it for the past hour. I'll tell you if I ever find anything.

I am afraid it is just a nice coincidence. I will try to show that $\boldsymbol{Z}$ doesn't follow a Gaussian distribution. In doing so, I will also give a reason that led you to conjecture this result. Using the representation of $Z$ suggested by Gérard Letac, we can actually compute all the moments of $Z$. This representation is given by the following lemma:

Lemma: $Z$ has the same distribution as $U=A+BV$ where $A:=\frac{Y_1+Y_2}{2}$, $B:=\frac{Y_1-Y_2}{2}$ and $V\sim\mathrm{Unif}(-1,1)$ are independent.
proof. First, let's show that $A$ and $B$ are independent: $(Y_1,Y_2)^\intercal$ follows a multivariate normal distribution with identity covariance matrix, therefore
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}A\\B\end{array}\right)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right)}_{\phi}\left(\begin{array}{c} Y_1\\ Y_2 \end{array}\right)$$
also follows a multivariate normal distribution with covariance matrix
$$\Sigma:=\phi \phi^\intercal = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 0& 1\end{array}\right)$$
$A$ and $B$ are independent as they are uncorrelated components of a normally distributed vector. [...]

$Z$ is symmetric, therefore $\mathbb E\left[Z^{2n+1}\right]=0$ for all $n$. For the even moments:
$$\mathbb E\left[Z^{2n}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\mathbb E\left[A^k\right]\mathbb E\left[B^{2n-k}\right]\mathbb E\left[V^{2n-k}\right]$$
$V$ is also symmetric, so whenever $k$ is odd, $\mathbb E\left[V^{2n-k}\right]=0$. The above formula reduces to
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[Z^{2n}\right]&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{2k}\mathbb E\left[A^{2k}\right]\mathbb E\left[B^{2n-2k}\right]\mathbb E\left[V^{2n-2k}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{2k}\mathbb E\left[A^{2k}\right]\mathbb E\left[|B|^{2n-2k}\right]\mathbb E\left[|V|^{2n-2k}\right]
\end{align*}
We need to identify the distributions of these three random variables:

Distribution of $A$: notice that
$$A=\frac{Y_1+Y_2}{2}=\frac{\min(X_1,X_2)+\max(X_1,X_2)}{2}=\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$$
so that $A\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\sigma^2=1/2)$. Therefore, its moments (even) are given by
$$\mathbb E\left[A^{2k}\right]=\frac{(2k)!}{4^{k}k!}$$
Distribution of $|B|$:
$$|B|=\frac{|Y_1-Y_2|}{2}=\frac{|X_1-X_2|}{2}$$
$X_1-X_2\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2)$, so $2^{-1/2}|X_1-X_2|$ follows a half normal distribution with parameter $\theta=\sqrt{\pi/2}$, whose (even) moments are given by
$$\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{|X_1-X_2|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2K}\right]=(2K-1)!!$$
(see double factorial) and therefore
$$\mathbb E\left[|B|^{2n-2k}\right]=\frac{(2n-2k-1)!!}{2^{n-k}}=\frac{(2n-2k)!}{4^{n-k}(n-k)!}$$
Distribution of $|V|$: we know that $V\sim \mathrm{Unif}(-1,1)$, so $|V|\sim\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$, and
$$\mathbb E\left[|V|^{2n-2k}\right]=\frac{1}{2n-2k+1}$$

Combining everything gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[Z^{2n}\right]&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{4^{k}k!}\cdot\frac{(2n-2k)!}{4^{n-k}(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{1}{2n-2k+1}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2n-2k+1}\right)}_{\displaystyle x_n}
\end{align*}
To show that $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, it would be equivalent to show that the quantity $x_n$ between parenthesis is $\sigma^{2n}$ (or $\sqrt[n]{x_n}\equiv \sigma^2$). Indeed, the Gaussian distribution (among other distributions) is characterized by the sequence of its moments (see moment problem). Here is a table with the first values of $x_n$ and its $n$-th root:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 1 & 2 & 3& 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
x_n&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{7}{15}&\frac{12}{35}&\frac{83}{315}&\frac{146}{693}&\frac{523}{3003}&\frac{952}{6435}&\frac{14051}{109385}&\frac{26206}{230945} \\ \hline
\sqrt[n]{x_n}&\frac{2}{3}&0.68\dots&0.70\dots&0.72\dots&0.73\dots&0.75\dots&0.76\dots&0.77\dots&0.79\dots \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
$\sqrt[n]{x_n}$ is not constant, and therefore $Z$ isn't normally distributed (of course, it is enough to check that $x_1\ne \sqrt{x_2}$). However, the first few terms are really close to $2/3$, I think that explains why $\mathcal{N}(0,2/3)$ is a good approximation for the distrution of $Z$.

Understood, thank you for the clear and deep answer!

You're welcome. If you think my answer is complete enough, please consider accepting it!

Right, thanks for reminding me!

Having an explicit density for $U$ is impossible. In the other hand $U$ is a symmetric variable and you can calculate all the even moments by considering $2Y_3=Y_1+Y_2$ and $2Y_4=Y_1-Y_2$ and considering $V$ uniform on $(-1,1)$. Since $Y_3,$ $Y_4$ and $V$ are independent and since $U=Y_3+VY_4$ the calculation of $U^{2n}$ is easy for the small values on $n.$
Edit: Suppose that the uniform law of $V$ on $[-1,1]$ is replaced by another symmetric distribution on $[-1,1]$ It is easy to see that $U$ is normal when $|V|$ is Dirac. But this is an amusing exercise to prove that the converse is true, using the usual test on non normality  that if $Z\sim N(0,1)$ then $E(Z^4)=3.$

Thank you for the answer. I belive your $U$ is my $Z$. Having seen the simulation in my answer below it seems that the distribution of $Z$ is very close to be a Gaussian. Is there any reasonable explanation for this? Or is it just math work?

Sorry for changing the notations $U$ pour uniform. For me $Z$ is something creating automatisms for $N(0,1)$! I could deal with a circle of center R and radius C, this is just more complicated. By the way we have indeed $E(U^2)=2/3$ but $E(U^4)=7/5>12/9$, which proves that $U$ is not normal, but the difference 1/15 is not big.

Very nice, thanks for the clarifications!

Just an update on this, by doing a quick simulation I have find out that the distribution of $Z$ is empirically very close to a $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{2}{3})$, I was wondering, can we do better than this?
Here is the plot:

